# getting Numerical Value from Radio button using JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, function

Why this code is not returning the value.When I click Calculate, it does not work.

Comment: `ageNumerical == ...` should be `ageNumerical = ...` - `==` is used to compare two values. But you need an assignment which is a single `=`

Comment: `==` is a comparison, not an assignment, meaning `ageNumerical` never gets assigned, meaning you're returning `undefined` every time. You can also shorten your function considerably by using a dictionary and `break`ing out of/returning from the middle of the loop

Comment: Demo of shortened function http://jsbin.com/ficowibaya/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparison is `==`

Assignment is `=`.

You need `ageNumerical = 0;`

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/bz1b6geg/).

Here is the snippet.

```js
function getValue() {

    var a = patientAge();
    var b = patientBmi();
    var c = history();
    var d = patientDiet();

    var totalValue;
    totalValue = a + b + c + d;

    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = totalValue;
}

function patientAge() {
    var age = document.getElementsByName('ageRange');
    var ageBracket;
    var ageNumerical;

    for (var i = 0; i < age.length; i++) {
        if (age[i].checked) {
            ageBracket = age[i].value;
        }
    }

    if (ageBracket == "1-25") {
        ageNumerical = 0;
    } else if (ageBracket == "26-40") {
        ageNumerical = 5;
    } else if (ageBracket == "41-60") {
        ageNumerical = 8;
    } else {
        ageNumerical = 10;
    }
    return ageNumerical;
}

function patientBmi() {
    var bmi = document.getElementsByName('bmiRange');
    var bmiValue;
    var bmiNumerical;
    for (var i = 0; i < bmi.length; i++) {
        if (bmi[i].checked) {
            bmiValue = bmi[i].value;
        }
    }
    if (bmiValue == "0-25") {
        bmiNumerical = 0;
    } else if (bmiValue == "26-30") {
        bmiNumerical = 0;
    } else if (bmiValue == "31-35") {
        bmiNumerical = 9;
    } else {
        bmiNumerical = 10;
    }
    return bmiNumerical;

}

function history() {
    var patientHistory = document.getElementsByName('familyHistory');
    var historyAnswer;
    var historyNumerical;

    for (var i = 0; i < patientHistory.length; i++) {
        if (patientHistory[i].checked) {
            historyAnswer = patientHistory[i].value;

        }
    }
    if (historyAnswer == "No") {
        historyNumerical = 0;
    } else if (historyAnswer == "Grandparent") {
        historyNumerical = 7;
    } else if (historyAnswer == "Sibling") {
        historyNumerical = 15;
    } else {
        historyNumerical = 15;
    }

    return historyNumerical;

}


function patientDiet() {
    var dietQuestion = document.getElementsByName('dietHabits');
    var dietAnswer;
    var dietNumerical;
    for (var i = 0; i < dietQuestion.length; i++) {
        if (dietQuestion[i].checked) {
            dietAnswer = dietQuestion[i].value;
        }
    }

    if (dietAnswer == "Low sugar") {
        dietNumerical = 0;
    } else if (dietAnswer == "Normal sugar") {
        dietNumerical = 0;
    } else if (dietAnswer == "Quite high sugar") {
        dietNumerical = 7;
    } else {
        dietNumerical = 10;
    }

    return dietNumerical;

}
```

```html
<div id="ageQuestion">
  <p>How old are you?</p>
  <label for="age1">1-25</label>
  <input type="radio" name="ageRange" value="1-25" />
  <label for="age2">26-40</label>
  <input type="radio" name="ageRange" value="26-40" />
  <label for="age3">41-60</label>
  <input type="radio" name="ageRange" value="41-60" />
  <label for="age4">60+</label>
  <input type="radio" name="ageRange" value="60+" />
</div>
<div id="bmi">
  <p>What is your BMI?</p>
  <label for="bmiLevel">0-25</label>
  <input type="radio" name="bmiRange" value="0-25" />
  <label for="bmiLevel">26-30</label>
  <input type="radio" name="bmiRange" value="26-30" />
  <label for="bmiLevel">31-35</label>
  <input type="radio" name="bmiRange" value="31-35" />
  <label for="bmiLevel">35+</label>
  <input type="radio" name="bmiRange" value="35+" />
</div>
<div id="family">
  <p>Does anybody in your family have Diabetes?</p>
  <label for="history">No</label>
  <input type="radio" name="familyHistory" value="No" />
  <label for="history">Grandparent</label>
  <input type="radio" name="familyHistory" value="Grandparent" />
  <label for="history">Sibling</label>
  <input type="radio" name="familyHistory" value="Sibling" />
  <label for="history">Parent</label>
  <input type="radio" name="familyHistory" value="Parent" />
</div>
<div id="diet">
  <p>How would you describe your diet?</p>
  <label for="diet">Low sugar</label>
  <input type="radio" name="dietHabits" value="Low sugar" />
  <label for="diet">Normal sugar</label>
  <input type="radio" name="dietHabits" value="Normal sugar" />
  <label for="diet">Quite high sugar</label>
  <input type="radio" name="dietHabits" value="Quite high sugar" />
  <label for="diet">High sugar</label>
  <input type="radio" name="dietHabits" value="High sugar" />
</div>
<button onclick="getValue()">Calculate</button>
<p id="message"></p>
```

Comment: I have sorted the ageNumerical == 0; and added further code.I guess I am omitting something???

Comment: Check out my updated answer. Your code still had `ageNumerical == 0;`. I removed it. You `JS` also had one extra `}`.

Comment: It is a good practice to "Accept" and "Upvote" (if possible) the answer which is helpful as it help everyone who visits this question in future

Answer (score 0):

Change == to = when assigning values.

```
ageNumerical == 0;
```

to

```
ageNumerical = 0;
```

Comment: I cant believe it , I overlooked this mistake! Thank you.